# Do i have static or dynamic boost libraries?

Tags: c++, boost

I have ran `bjam.exe --build-dir="C:\build-boost" --build-type=minimal msvc stage`

and now I have libraries .lib with these headers, for example

```
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_45
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_45
```

I believe these should be static libraries for debug and release version. When I run the compiler with `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)` it gives an error `LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-sgd-1_45.lib'`  It is looking for one with `-sgd`

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try building using "--build-type=complete” as this will build all supported variants of the libraries. See section "5.3.4   Invoke bjam" in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Answer (score 29):

Something that is kind of confusing is there are two 'static' options for building boost with MSVC.

B2.exe takes the option `link=static` which tells boost that you want to link it (boost) statically. If you are compiling your VC project with /MT or /MTd you will also need to use the `runtime-link=static` option to tell boost that you will be linking to the VC runtime libraries statically.

It is the second `runtime-link=static` which puts the -s in the .lib name.

My command line for building boost was

```
b2.exe --toolset=msvc variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static stage
```

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with this but with a bunch of different dependencies, not just boost. I think you just made it click for me! (3 years later).

Answer (score 4):

You have the dynamic versions. The static ones are delimited by having the "s" in the name. Make sure you specified `link=static` on the `bjam` command line. If not, you'll have to rebuild to make the static versions.

Comment: does it suppose to give me any `.dlls` at the end? I only got the `.libs` in stage folder.

Comment: @snoz: You're looking in the wrong folder then. On Windows boxes, the libs are treated as build artifacts, which are then copied into the output folder when compile of each library is complete. You'll have to find where the directory containing both the dlls and the libs are located.

Answer (score 2):

See [Boost getting started windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) section 6.3 naming and [section 6.1 on Unix naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming)

For static libraries there should be a s in there e.g. -sgd so you have dynamic libraries

Comment: I don't think it should be "egd", it should be "sgd" or just "s".

Answer (score 2):

here is how i break it down

libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-sgd-1_45.lib

```
lib- if boost library starts with lib then its a static library , shared library do not start with lib prefix. Also static library will have a '-s' in the name.

mt- multi-threaded , obtained by specifying threading=multi when you ran bjam or b2.This is the default threading.

g- use debug libraries for building the code
d- build a debug version of your code
```

So your compiler is searching for  multi-threaded static debug library(mt-sgd) as you ran with /MTd(Creates a debug multithreaded executable file using LIBCMTD.lib). I guess by default it must be searching for static library. If you want a dynamic library,  insert these lines in your code or define a macro

```
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this document:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming

There you can find the meanings of all letters and how you can build the boost accordingly also...