# boost link error LNK2038: “boost_log_abi” “v2s_mt_nt6” doesn't match “v2_mt_nt6"

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2015

what does this link error mean ? and how to fix it

```
error LNK2038: “boost_log_abi” “v2s_mt_nt6” doesn't match  “v2_mt_nt6"
```

i have tried

```
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x601)
```

Comment: i havent defined BOOST_LOG_DOXYGEN_PASS when building boost with b2, why it is v2s_mt_nt6 not v2_mt_nt6

Comment: Could you share a little more context on how your build is set up (what files you link with, or the build command that actually fails)? I suspect you link against a statically built version of Boost, but I need a little more data to back that up

Comment: i downloaded a pre-built version of boost, and now its work,  i encountered some error when building from the boost source code to generate dynamic library. thanks a lot.

Comment: so the `s` in `v2s_mt_nt6` means static ?

Comment: Yes. It's possible that your build of boost actually ended up generating static libraries - with many of them, you don't notice the differences, but Boost.Log causes trouble. I'll post this as an answer so other people can find it when they search for it.

Comment: add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601) This worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Boost.Log library seems to have been built with different flags than your main program.

From [`config.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/log/detail/config.hpp), we can see what these ABI names mean:

- `v2s_mt_nt6` is statically linked, with multithreading support, on Windows Vista or higher (version 6)
- `v2_mt_nt6` is *dynamically* linked, with multithreading support, on Windows Vista or higher (version 6)

The `BOOST_LOG_DLL` macro decides which of the two paths to use. It is defined if any of `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` are defined.

If you statically link against Boost.Log (via a `.lib` files or similar), you *must not* define either of these two macros.<sup>1</sup>

This means that you can either remove the extra preprocessor definitions (because you are trying to link to a static library) or use a dynamic library version of Boost (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4619764/1106415) on how to set that up on Windows).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Note that some libraries [ignore those flags outright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051417/1106415). Boost.Log seems to be one of the few that actually cause issues if these macros are misconfigured</sup>