# Visual C++ executable will not run without Boost DLLs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake

I'm using `Visual Studio` to compile a `C++` project using `CMake` as the build system.

Furthermore I'm linking against the [`Boost`](https://www.boost.org) library. The output executable however will not run if the following `Boost` `DLL`s are not found in the `PATH` environment variable: `boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_69.dll` and `boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_69.dll`.

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140)), I tried using the `/MT` ("Causes the application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library") and also the `/MD` ("Causes the application to use the multithread-specific and DLL-specific version of the run-time library") compilation flag but besides affecting the file size, the `DLL` dependence on `Boost` did not change.

I also specified the following `CMake` variables:

```
set(BOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
```

This did not force static linking against the `Boost` libraries either. I want to generate an executable which does not dynamically depend on `Boost` but only on the core `C++` runtime libraries so any other machine can run it without shipping `Boost` or any `Boost` `DLL`s. It is totally fine if the file size increases quite a bit.

[Adding the following preprocessor define to `main.cpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739745/3764804) does not work either:

```
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB 1
```

How can I really build the standalone executable?

Comment: Do you have static libs installed and are you linking against them?

Comment: @ThomasSablik: I have libraries named like `boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_69.lib` and `boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_69.lib`. Those are from the precompiled libraries download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries
I assume they are the dynamic ones (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619764) so I still have to compile static ones and then it should work as expected?

Comment: Yes, looks like dynamic libs. Try it with static libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I just misspelled setting `Boost` to use the static libraries:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

`CMake` variables are case-sensitive so spelling out `Boost` with capital letters does not work.

The precompiled `Windows` binaries already contain everything needed so compiling yourself is not necessary if you just want to link against the static libraries.