# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_69.lib'

Tags: boost

I can not find 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_69.lib' of boost (tried building it myself and also downloaded the binaries for vs141 and x32 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.69.0/)

what I have is 
libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_69.lib from the downloaded binaries
and
libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-s-x32-1_69.lib that I built myself

where can I find this file?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the `-s` in the build. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619764/do-i-have-static-or-dynamic-boost-libraries), you would use `link=static` and `runtime-link=static`. I have not tried that. But I know it will build this version if you `--build-type=complete` on the b2 command line. And, it is just as well you build your own to keep compiler/SDK version conflicts out of your work.

Lots of information on `b2` [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#invoke-b2).